# windows環境でCaboChaをPython3にバインディング出来ません。

Tags: python, python3, mecab, cabocha

表題の通り、windows7(64bit)でCaboChaをどうしてもバインディングできません。関連Qiita記事を何度も読み直し、必要なVisual Studio(14.1)を導入するなどをして何度もトライしていますが、画像の通りエラーが出て一向に成功しません。

環境は下記の通りです。

- Python3.7.1(32bit)
- MeCab0.996(公式の32bit)
- CaboCha0.69

どうか皆様のお力をお借りできればと思います。
何卒よろしくお願い致します。

#### 追記

インストール手順ですが、

1. もしやAnacondaなので不具合が起こるのかと思い、Anaconda、mecab、cabochaをアンインストール。
2. python3.7.1(32bit)をインストールしPATH等も上書き。
3. MeCabをインストールしました。Python上でも使用可能なようdllをpython/Lib/site-packagesへコピーし、cmdからpip installコマンドでmecab-python-windowsをインストール。MeCabの動作はPython上でも全く問題ありません。
4. CaboCha0.69とソース(CaboCha0.69tar.bz2)を公式サイトからダウンロードし、それぞれ実行とデスクトップに解凍をしました。CaboCha単体では動作は問題ないです。
5. Qiita等の記事を読みつつ必要なコンパイラ等をインストールしました。
6. ソース内のpython/python.pyを書き換え、画像の通り実行してみてもなかなか上手くいきません。

```sh
C:\Users\sorshall\Desktop\cabocha-0.69\python>python setup.py install
running install
running build
running build_py
running build_ext
building '_CaboCha' extension
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\bin\HostX86\x86\cl.exe /c /nologo /0x /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\CaboCha\sdk" -IC:\python371_32\include -IC:\python371_32\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\ATLMFC\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\include" "-IC:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017" -IC:\python371_32\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\include" /EHsc /TpCaboCha_wrap.cxx /Fo build\temp.win32-3.7\Release\CaboCha_wrap.obj
CaboCha_wrap.cxx
c:\python371_32\include\pyconfig.h(59): fatal error C1083: include ファイルを開けません。'io.h':No such file or directory
error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2017\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.16.27023\\bin\\HostX86\\x86\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
```

#### 関連記事

windowsでCaboCha-Python3バインディング
https://qiita.com/ayuchiy/items/d8afcffb27fcc10f6947

WindowsにCabocha 0.68をいれてPythonで係り受けを解析してみる
https://qiita.com/mima_ita/items/161cd869648edb30627b